# Trigonometric proof with calculus

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, rolles-theorem

How do we prove that $x^2=x\sin{x}+\cos{x}$ for exactly two values of $x$?

I thought of the sandwich theorem or such, getting only:

$-1\leq\sin{x}\leq1$

$-x\leq x\sin{x}\leq x$

$-x+\cos{x}\leq x\sin{x}+\cos{x}\leq x+\cos{x}$

Then replace the expression in the middle with $x^2$ because that is what says in the first equality:

$-x+\cos{x}\leq x+\cos{x}$

Then I got the idea to get the derivative for all three sides:

$-1-\sin{x}\leq2x+\sin{x}\leq1-\sin{x}$

Now we sum $\sin{x}$ in all three sides:

$-1\leq2x+\sin{x}\leq1$

That says that for f'(x), $x$ is zero.

However, I don't even know if I am doing well. What is next? Can you explain to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no. of distinct real roots of the equation $x^2=x\sin x+\cos x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999433/no-of-distinct-real-roots-of-the-equation-x2-x-sin-x-cos-x)